# android arraylist get hashmap position

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList HashMap like the one below.

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrType = new ArrayList<>();
```

with the following values added into it

```
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("type", "TRIMMER");
    map.put("request", "5");
    map.put("actual", "0");
    mArrType.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("type", "HAND ROUTER");
    map.put("request", "6");
    map.put("actual", "0");
    mArrType.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("type", "AIR COMPRESSOR");
    map.put("request", "6");
    map.put("actual", "0");
    mArrType.add(map);
```

Question is how can i get the position of a hashmap from arraylist. eg : hashmap with 'type' trimmer has a position 0 in arraylist,  I want to retrieve the position value "0"

Comment: Of course, what you *really* should be doing here is creating a `class Equipment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write a small util method

```
private static int getTrimmerTypeMapPosition(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrType) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mArrType.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> mp = mArrType.get(i);
            if (mp.get("type").equals("TRIMMER")) {
                return i;
            }    
        }    
        return -1;    
    }
```

To make this method very generic, have "type" and "TRIMMER" as method params, so that you can just pass any key and value pairs to check with.

Comment: I suppose better to check like this `"TRIMMER".equals(mp.get("type"))` to prevent exception in case when `mp.get("type")` returns null.

Comment: @Roman_D I'll leave that decisions to OP as he will check what if type is not present in map at all.:)

Answer (score 0):

That's not efficiently possible with your data structure. You can either store the own position in each `HashMap` or loop through all entries and search for the one with the type you are looking for.

You can, of course, define another `HashMap<String, Integer>` which maps all your type strings to the corresponding `ArrayList` index.

Comment: I dont think OP need extra map. Just iterate over list and look up for type ?

Comment: Yes, but if he has very many entries in the ArrayList it's more efficient to hash it.

Comment: You have a point, I've tried store position value in each hashmap and it works. But I marked suresh answer as the best, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Others answer is also correct, but you can do this thing using `Java8` also.

E.g.:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, mArrType.size()).
                filter(i -> mArrType.get(i).get("type").equals("TRIMMER"))
                .findFirst().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Not just map, needed index of map which have a "type" value "Trimmer"

Comment: Yes he is, thank for pointing this thing. i have updated my answer accordingly.